# IIS advanced logging won't function under load?

Tags: iis, iis-7

Does it make sense that IIS will become extremely slow and unresponsive when using IIS Advanced Logging to log all incoming requests?

I have some rules that divide the incoming requests into 5 files according to their prefix. I found out that a simple stress test of 100 users sending requests nonstop for half an hour. The IIS process memory goes all the way up to 4GB and won't recycle at 500MB limit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there are two separate issues here.

1) IIS does not seem to be respecting the Application Pool Recycling criteria when a process exceeds a specified working set

2) IIS Advanced Logging seems to be consuming large amounts of memory given this configuration.

Regarding #2 - one suggestion is to start by disabling filtering and writing to a single log to see if that alleviates the memory consumption issue.  If you don't mind sharing the relevant snippets of the applicationHost.config and/or web.config files that contain your Advanced Logging settings and log definitions, that would be very helpful for repro'ing the issue.

Thanks,

Jack Freelander

IIS Media Services

Answer (score 0):

Was the data written to the files correctly when not under load?  Also, was the 500MB limit per log?

Comment: Not under load, it was ok. The limit was not size-wise but every 5 minutes a new file was opened.